# Sprite Kit - Resting physics body object at correct collision contact point

Tags: objective-c, ios7, collision-detection, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am trying to make a game about balls and using sprite kit with physics body for IOS 7. My problem is about resting objects when contact / collide. Here is my code in `didBeginContact`:

```
[contact.bodyA setVelocity:CGVectorMake(0, 0)];
[contact.bodyB setVelocity:CGVectorMake(0, 0)];
contact.bodyA.resting = YES;
contact.bodyB.resting = YES;
```

Actually `contact.bodyA` is already resting but I just set it to make sure both objects are set to resting. The problem is, balls are not touching to each other even if I set `contact.bodyA(or B).resting = YES`.

This is what I want:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8JTk.png

This is what happening sometimes:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWORO.png

As you can see in second picture, the blue ball is a bit far from other balls. Is there any other way to magnet the ball at contact point always?

Answer (score 0):

This could potentially be a problem with the physics body. I'm assuming you're using `[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:spriteWidth/2]`. Are you certain your sprite image is the correct size and matches w/ the radius you're feeding the physics body constructor?

Perhaps you could store the position of the object in a property `prevPosition`, and when a collision is detected, return the position of the sprite node to `prevPosition` and set the body to `resting`?
`

Comment: Yes this is how I am creating SKPhysicsBody. Also I am pretty sure image is correct sized and matching because the balls are resting correctly when I push directly to the ball. But when I am throwing ball through wall, depends on angle, ball's velocity is increasing / multiplying after hitting the wall (I also need to solve this by setting constant velocity somehow). After bouncing from the wall, the ball is going much more faster than first position and depends on this speed, it is resting far from other ball(s).

Comment: Just tell me if that solution works, I believe it's the general method

Comment: Do you mean store previous position in each frame draw cycle (such as `update` method)? If you mean this; well this is very unoptimized solution... Instead, I can try to do something with `contact.position`. But I don't know what is the `contact.position` exactly yet.. Still researching it.

Comment: Strange, there's no class reference for the SKPhysicsContact class... is it not a class at all?

Comment: Where did you find a reference to contact.position?

Comment: Ah sorry it is just a miss typo; it is actually `contact.contactPoint`. And here is SKPhysicsContact class reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContact/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsContact/contactPoint

Comment: Ahh. So if you can just pull the contactPoint from the SKContact, what's there left to do?

Comment: Because position of ball is pointing to center of the ball and `contactPoint` is only returning touch point (external intersection of circles).